# How to limit link to only div and not Bootstrap column?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have this div with a class of `.win_box`:

The div is surrounded by a Bootstrap column. The link is allowing the user to allow the link throughout the entire Bootstrap column itself. I only want users to have access to this link on the actual div itself. How do I do this?

```css
.win_box {
      position: relative;
      left: -12px;
      height: 110px;
      width: 196px;
      background: #353535;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-g" id='title'>
       <a href='#'> <div class='win_box'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i> </div> </a>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

> display:inline-block;

to the .win_box class and you are good to go.

```
.win_box {
      position: relative;
      left: -12px;
      height: 110px;
      width: 196px;
      background: #353535;
      display:inline-block;
    }
```

and you are good to go

Comment: Thanks, the simple answers are the best :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a `display: inline-block;`

```css
.win_box {
      position: relative;
      left: -12px;
      height: 110px;
      width: 196px;
      background: #353535;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-g" id='title'>
    <div class='win_box' onClick="window.location='https://google.com';" > <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i> </div> </a>  
</div>
```

The other option is to use JS for linking. `onclick="location.href='www.google.com'"`

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-g" id='title'>
       <div class='win_box' onclick="location.href='www.google.com'"> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i> </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/6n2bpep4/2/